# AVCaptureMetadataObjectDelegate not receiving callback

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcaptureoutput

I am making QR scanner. My code is working when all of it written in one place inside `ViewController` but when I modularised it then I am not getting callback inside `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraSource : NSObject {

    private var session                     : AVCaptureSession?
    private var inputDevice             : AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    private var videoPreviewLayer   : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    private var captureMetadataOutput : AVCaptureMetadataOutput?

    func setCaptureMetadataOutput() {
        self.captureMetadataOutput = nil
        self.captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    }

    func getCaptureMetadataOutput() -> AVCaptureMetadataOutput? {
        return self.captureMetadataOutput
    }

    func setInputDevice(inputDevice : AVCaptureDeviceInput?) {
        self.inputDevice = inputDevice
    }

    func getInputDevice() -> AVCaptureDeviceInput? {
        return self.inputDevice
    }

    func setSession(session : AVCaptureSession?) {
        self.session = session
    }

    func getSession() -> AVCaptureSession? {
        return self.session
    }

    func setMetadataObjects(metaObjects : [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType], delegate : AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate) {
        assert(self.captureMetadataOutput != nil)
        self.captureMetadataOutput!.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(delegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.captureMetadataOutput!.metadataObjectTypes = metaObjects
    }

    func initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity : AVLayerVideoGravity, orientation : AVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
        assert(session != nil)

        videoPreviewLayer                                                           = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session!)
        videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity                                 = videoGravity
        videoPreviewLayer!.connection!.videoOrientation = orientation
    }

    func addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView : UIImageView) {
        assert(self.videoPreviewLayer != nil)

        imageView.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer!)
        self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = imageView.bounds
    }

    func startSession() {
        assert(session != nil)
        self.session!.startRunning()
    }


    /*==========================================================================
    STATIC FUNCTIONS
    ==========================================================================*/

    static func getBackCamera() -> AVCaptureDevice {
        return AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)!
    }

    static func getFrontCamera() -> AVCaptureDevice {
        return AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)!
    }

    static func isCameraAvailable() -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let count : Int = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                                                                 mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                                                                 position: .unspecified).devices.count
            if count > 0 { return true }
        }
        else {
            let count = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video).count
            if count > 0 { return true }
        }
        return false
    }


    /*==========================================================================
    CAMERA BUILDER CLASS
    ==========================================================================*/

    class Builder {

        var cameraSource : CameraSource

        init() {
            cameraSource = CameraSource()
        }

        func createSession() -> Builder {
            if (cameraSource.getSession() != nil) {
                cameraSource.setSession(session: nil)
            }
            cameraSource.setSession(session: AVCaptureSession())
            return self
        }

        func setSessionPreset(preset : AVCaptureSession.Preset) -> Builder {
            assert(cameraSource.getSession() != nil)

            cameraSource.getSession()!.sessionPreset = preset
            return self
        }

        func attachInputDevice(camera : AVCaptureDevice) throws -> Builder {

            try self.prepareInputDevice(camera: camera)
            try self.addInputToSession()

            assert(cameraSource.inputDevice != nil)
            return self
        }

        func addOutputToSessionForMetaData() throws -> CameraSource {
            cameraSource.setCaptureMetadataOutput()

            assert(cameraSource.getSession() != nil && cameraSource.getCaptureMetadataOutput() != nil)

            if !cameraSource.getSession()!.canAddOutput(cameraSource.getCaptureMetadataOutput()!) {
                throw AppErrorCode.cameraError("Unable to attach output to camera session")
            }
            cameraSource.getSession()!.addOutput(cameraSource.getCaptureMetadataOutput()!)

            return self.cameraSource
        }

        /*==========================================================================
        BUILDER PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
        ==========================================================================*/

        private func prepareInputDevice(camera : AVCaptureDevice) throws {
            do {
                let inputDevice = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
                cameraSource.setInputDevice(inputDevice: inputDevice)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                throw AppErrorCode.cameraError("Unable to attach input to camera session")
            }
        }

        private func addInputToSession() throws {
            if(cameraSource.getSession() == nil) {
                throw AppErrorCode.cameraError("Unable to create camera session")
            }

            assert(cameraSource.getInputDevice() != nil && cameraSource.getSession()!.canAddInput(cameraSource.getInputDevice()!))

            cameraSource.getSession()!.addInput(cameraSource.getInputDevice()!)
        }

    }


}
```

My QR scanner Code looks like

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

protocol QRScannerDelegate {
    func scannedData(_ scannedString : String)
}

class QRScanner : NSObject {

    private var cameraSource : CameraSource?

    var delegate : QRScannerDelegate?

    func prepareCamera (delegate : QRScannerDelegate) throws -> QRScanner {
        do {
            self.delegate = delegate
            self.cameraSource = try CameraSource
                .Builder()
                .createSession()
                .setSessionPreset(preset: .photo)
                .attachInputDevice(camera: CameraSource.getBackCamera())
                .addOutputToSessionForMetaData()

            self.cameraSource!.setMetadataObjects(metaObjects: [.qr], delegate: self as AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate)

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            self.cameraSource = nil
            throw AppErrorCode.cameraError("Unable to process camera with one or more issue")
        }

        return self
    }

    func initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity : AVLayerVideoGravity, orientation : AVCaptureVideoOrientation) -> QRScanner{
        assert(cameraSource != nil)

        self.cameraSource!.initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity: videoGravity, orientation: orientation)
        return self
    }

    func addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView : UIImageView) -> QRScanner{
        assert(cameraSource != nil)

        self.cameraSource!.addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView: imageView)
        return self
    }

    func startSession() {
        assert(cameraSource != nil)
        self.cameraSource!.startSession()
    }
}

extension QRScanner : AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        print("Delegate called")
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {

            self.delegate?.scannedData("No Data")

        } else {

            let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {

                if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                    print("Scanner Getting data: \(metadataObj.stringValue!)")
                    self.delegate?.scannedData(metadataObj.stringValue!)
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented the `QRScannerDelegate` in my `ViewController` but I am not getting anything in there. Moreover I am not getting callback inside `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` even.

I tried passing the `ViewController` instance as `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` then I was getting callback with the scanned info.

> So My question is why is this happening?

1) When I am passing normal class as `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` I am not getting callback. But.

2) Whe I am passing `UIViewController` instance as `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` then I am able to get callback.

UPDATE

This is how I am calling prepareCamera from my `View Controller`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        do {

            try QRScanner().prepareCamera(delegate: self)
                    .initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity: .resizeAspectFill, orientation: .portrait)
                    .addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView: self.qrScannerImageView)
                    .startSession()

        } catch {

            print("Some Camera Error")

        }
        self.createOverlay()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say for sure without knowing how you called `prepareCamera` as this is what triggers `setMetadataObjectsDelegate` but to me it looks like you may not be keeping a strong reference to `QRScanner` in your ViewController (instantiating it as in instance variable) Which could explain why the callback is getting hit when your ViewController is your `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` as the ViewController is still in memory.

It's also worth noting that if the ViewController is your `QRScannerDelegate` you will want to define delegate as `weak var delegate : QRScannerDelegate?` to prevent a memory leak.

EDIT:
Change

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        do {

            try QRScanner().prepareCamera(delegate: self)
                    .initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity: .resizeAspectFill, orientation: .portrait)
                    .addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView: self.qrScannerImageView)
                    .startSession()

        } catch {

            print("Some Camera Error")

        }
        self.createOverlay()
    }
```

to

```
var qrScanner = QRScanner()
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        do {

            try self.qrScanner.prepareCamera(delegate: self)
                    .initViewoPreviewLayer(videoGravity: .resizeAspectFill, orientation: .portrait)
                    .addVideoLayerToImageView(imageView: self.qrScannerImageView)
                    .startSession()

        } catch {

            print("Some Camera Error")

        }
        self.createOverlay()
    }
```

and change

```
protocol QRScannerDelegate {
    func scannedData(_ scannedString : String)
}
```

to

```
protocol QRScannerDelegate: class {
    func scannedData(_ scannedString : String)
}
```

To Allow a weak delegate

`AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` is tough, but you can do some really cool stuff with it! So keep at it.

I pulled some QRScanner code I wrote a while ago and put it into a gist for you if you want to check it out. Its a bit more stripped down than what you have, but you may find it helpful. 
https://gist.github.com/aChase55/733ea89af1bfa80c65971d3bc691f0b2

Comment: I have update my question with how I called prepare Camera. Can you give me some more insight?

Comment: Yes I am using using ViewController as QRScannerDelegate. I tried keeping variable as weak reference but xcode was showing error. So I had to remove it.

Comment: Can you tell me why we have to add 'class' in protocol for referencing it as weak variable, how does it help?

Comment: If you don't include `class` in your protocol, the protocol can be implemented by either a value type or reference type. By nature, it is not possible for value types to have a weak reference. Adding `class` to the protocol tells the compiler that only reference types will implement the protocol, making weak definitions legal. Since your view controller owns the delegate, and the delegate has a reference to the view controller, a memory leak will occur if the the delegates reference back to the view controller is not weak.

Comment: Here's some more info on value vs reference types
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10